# In this time dilation explanation, shouldn't gravity and mass affect the example?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers, approximations, models

recently i've started "exploring" general relativity, and found this example explaining time dilation caused by velocity:

[image]

The example was taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation

My question is, doesn't the example somehow assume that the glass has no mass, and therefore there is no gravity? Or even the light emitter? Or even the observer who is moving to the left. I mean, from what i've read, gravity also affects time dilation. Therefore, is the example, and the proof in general valid? Or does it somehow assume that gravity is non-existent?

If this is the case, how valid are theories or "proofs" that ignore part of the physics?

Comment: Special Relativity does not deal with gravitation.

Answer (score 2):

> Or does it somehow assume that gravity is non-existent?

The derivation explicitly assumes that the reference frame is inertial. This, in turn, assumes that:

1. the clock is in free fall
2. tidal effects are negligible

> If this is the case, how valid are theories or "proofs" that ignore part of the physics?

They are valid as long as the parts they ignored are small enough to be ignored. This is why it is important to understand the assumptions underlying any physics formula. You don’t need string theory or General Relativity to launch a rocket. Newtonian gravity is just fine. It ignores lots of the physics, but they are all small enough to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the clock being in freefall, doesn't make it so the gravity of the mirrors themselves on light is non-existent, right?

Comment: @user1508072 it is negligible

Comment: "Newtonian gravity is just fine".No Newtonian gravity is just plain wrong.It allows mediation of gravity >c which is impossible.

Comment: @appliedSciences that doesn’t matter for launching rockets, it is negligible

Comment: @Dale Just because a model describes what happens at a small range of observations doesnt mean it is correct.Folllowing your reasoning one can say that the aether is a good model

Comment: @appliedSciences I didn’t claim that Newtonian gravity is “correct” (it is unlikely that any modern theory is “correct” in that sense). I claimed it is fine for launching rockets, which it is. Launching rockets is well within Newtonian gravity’s experimentally confirmed domain of validity. Your concern about “correctness” is irrelevant for that. If you wish to discuss further please post to physicsforums.com, comments are not intended for discussion here

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational time dilation is incredibly small.  Even on Earth it's only fractions of a nanosecond per year.  It was shown that the time dilation on earth compared to 10,000 km altitude is only one second per century.    So, as others have said, the gravitational time dilation of your mirrors would be far too small to take into account, and would be vastly outweighed by the kinetic time dilation of the moving observer.

It is normal in this type of experiment to ignore such a small effect.